# Static class updates static variables, but static methods do not update static variables

Tags: java, static-methods

I searched through a few pages, but most seem to be just having comprehension issues as to what static means.The problem I have lies in that we are using a static class, FocusListener, and ActionListener. The class that has the event handling calls on the static class, and when a JTextfield is fill and tabbed away from FocusListener updates that static variable instantly. When all JTextfields are filled and FocusListener has updated the variables, there is a submit JButton. As soon as the button is clicked, the static methods are called to finish of any variables that are calculated using the previously updated variables. User is not aware of this. The variables do not update though, and I am curious if I am implementing this wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class WellParameters extends JInternalFrame implements FocusListener, ActionListener {
    JLabel  measuredDepthL, ..., pitGainL, drillBitSizeL, 
                mudInActivePitsL, mainPanelLabel;
        JTextField  measuredDepthT, ..., pitGainT, drillBitSizeT, mudInActivePitsT;
        JPanel  mainPanel, firstPanel, secondPanel, thirdPanel, fourthPanel, submitButtonPanel;
        JButton submitButton;

        WellParameters() {  
            super("Well Parameters", true, true, false, true);
            this.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 385);
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            ...//GUI Stuff

            this.add(submitButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {} //Ignore this!

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        try {
            if(e.getSource() == measuredDepthT) {
                KillWellCalculations.measuredDepth = Integer.parseInt(measuredDepthT.getText());

              ...//Others 

            } else if(e.getSource() == mudInActivePitsT) {
                KillWellCalculations.mudInActivePits = Double.parseDouble(mudInActivePitsT.getText());
            }
        } catch (Exception ignore) {}

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            if(e.getSource() == submitButton) {
            System.out.println(KillWellCalculations.pumpEfficiency);
            KillWellCalculations.setPressureBeforeCasingBurstAndFormationFracture(); //Doesn't work
            KillWellCalculations.setCirculatingPressures();
            KillWellCalculations.setTriplexPumpCapacity();
            System.out.println(KillWellCalculations.mudInActivePits);
            System.out.println(KillWellCalculations.pumpFactor);
            System.out.println(KillWellCalculations.finalCirculatingPressure);}
        }
        catch(Exception ignore) {}
    }
}
```

That was the GUI, and this is the static class... They are 2 separate classes. Not in the same file.
package killwellsheet;

```
public class KillWellCalculations {

    static int measuredDepth;           //Total Depth from open hole to bottom

        ... //Tons of other variables

    static double totalStrokes;         //add strokes

    //Used to set different circulating pressures for the well
    public static void setCirculatingPressures() {
        initialCirculatingPressure = circulatingPressureKillRate + shutInDrillPipePressure;
        finalCirculatingPressure = circulatingPressureKillRate * (killMudWeight/currentMudWeight);
    }   
    //Calculates capacity of anypipe
    private static double pipeCapacity(double length, double insideDiameter) {
        return length * ((insideDiameter*insideDiameter)/1029.4);
    }
    //Calculates capacity of the annulus/open hole
    private static double annulusCapacity(double length, double insideDiameter, double outsideDiameter) {
        return length * (((insideDiameter*insideDiameter)-(outsideDiameter*outsideDiameter))/1029.4);
    } 

         ... //Other functions

    //Set the casing burst pressure
    public static void setPressureBeforeCasingBurstAndFormationFracture() {
        beforeCasingBurst = burstPressure*0.70;
        beforeFormationFracture = (0.052*casingShoeDepth)*(fracGradientMWEquivalent - currentMudWeight);
    }
    public static void bariteNeedAndVolumeIncrease() {
        bariteSacksRequired = (totalMudVolume/100)*((1099*(killMudWeight-currentMudWeight))/(28.35-killMudWeight));
        increaseInMudVolume = 0.091*bariteSacksRequired;
    }
    public static void pumpStrokes() {
        surfaceToBit = (mudInDrillString)/pumpFactor;
        bitToSurface = (mudInAnnulus)/pumpFactor;
        totalStrokes = surfaceToBit + bitToSurface;
    }
}//end class
```

Comment: I used those line prints as troubleshooting. They show me if the methods worked or not.

Comment: why are any variables and methods static here?  static inner class just means that the inner class does not require an instance of the outer class to exist.

Comment: Yes, as Hovercraft said, there is no reason at all for static methods and static variables here. It does only complicate everything.

Comment: They are two separate classes. The files are KillWellCalculations.java and WellParameters.java

Comment: @PetroEkos: I don't understand what your comment above, that the files are two separate classes, has to do with our concerns that you're using the static modifier inappropriately.  Again, all your variables and methods (except main, and few other exceptions), should not be static.

Comment: I guess since the class was nothing but calculations, we felt maybe we did not need to make any instances for it. Do you recommend just having a non-static class, and make the instance? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to print out a stack trace for debugging in your catch clauses. Ignoring exceptions can make code behavior difficult to follow.

Comment: @Petro: but since it has fields, the class appears to have a state and thus be more than a utility class.

Comment: @Hover Even as a normal class, and the method being called by one of the class variables, they do not update the values. Do I need to pass parameters, even though they are global? I think my problem is in calling my methods, and not whether they are static or not.

Comment: @Petro: I'm not sure.  You might want to create a much smaller program that is compilable, runnable, has a static method or two, and demonstrates your problem. That way we can run and modify your code and see for ourselves the problem, and perhaps be better at offering a solution.

Comment: @Petro: also, how do you know that the variables "aren't updating"?  Are you basing this on your GUI not showing changes in JTextFields or JLabels? If so, where do you set the text of these JTextFields/JLabels?  Again, a small compilable runnable program would help immensely.  This is called creating an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Hover I have some system.out.println() in the bottom that show me what the values are.  They gives me this output... 11.0
1.0
0.0
0.0 That shows the 1st two are from variables update from Jtextfield, and the 2nd after calling on method.

Comment: Please don't use mutable statics!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some clarifications... By reading your code, the only thing I see is that your class WellParameters implements the Interfaces FocusListener and ActionListener (not static classes). As far as I can figure out from your code, the methods **focusGained(FocusEvent e)** and **focusLost(FocusEvent e)** are implemented from the former Interface and updates the values of the static class, and you would depend on same calculated values in the ActionListener event **actionPerformed()**. The problem you are facing here is race-condition regarding the static instance values.

> http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html
>   A.3.4  Unreachable
>
> An object enters an unreachable state
>   when no more strong references to it
>   exist. When an object is unreachable,
>   it is a candidate for collection. Note
>   the wording: Just because an object is
>   a candidate for collection doesn't
>   mean it will be immediately collected.
>   The JVM is free to delay collection
>   until there is an immediate need for
>   the memory being consumed by the
>   object. It's important to note that
>   not just any strong reference will
>   hold an object in memory. These must
>   be references that chain from a
>   garbage collection root. GC roots are
>   a special class of variable that
>   includes
>
> Temporary variables on the stack (of any thread)
>
> **Static variables (from any class)**
>
> Special references from JNI native code

**Based on this Garbage Collection documentation, I suspect that ALL the static references of your class *KillWellCalculations* were eligible to be garbage collected after the call to the FocusEvent methods and, for this reason, they are not available by the time the event *actionPerformed()* is fired.**

You can still use the static methods of the class KillWellCalculations as a utility class only if this class is used by other classes. If not, you can transform it into a Value class  that holds the calculations for you, WITHOUT the static references. As you need to have a reference to an instance of a class that holds the values of the calculation... For instance:

```
public Class CalculatedValues {
     private int measuredDepth;
     private double mudInActivePits;

     public static CalculatedValues makeNew() {
          return new CalculatedValues();
     }

     public void setMeasuredDepth(String measuredDepthTString) {
           if (measuredDepthTString == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The measured depth must be provided.");
           }
           try {
                this.measuredDepth = Integer.parseInt(measuredDepthTString);
           } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value provided is not an interger.");
           }
     }
     public int getMeasuredDepth() {
          return measuredDepth;
     }

     public void setMudInActivePitsT(String mudInActivePitsTString) {
           if (mudInActivePitsTString == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The measured mudInActivePits must be provided.");
           }
           try {
                this.mudInActivePits = Double.parseDouble(measuredDepthTString);
           } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value provided is not an double.");
           }
     }
     public double getMeasuredDepth() {
          return mudInActivePits;
     }

     //...
     //...
     // MORE THE OTHER VALUES/PROPERTIES IMPORTANT/NEEDED BY THE CALCULATION. 

     public void doAllCalculations() {
          // YOU HAVE TO IMPLEMENT THE LOGIC FOR THOSE ONES, OPTIONALLY USING THE SAME UTILITY/HELPER STATIC METHODS FROM 
          setPressureBeforeCasingBurstAndFormationFracture();
          setCirculatingPressures();
          setTriplexPumpCapacity();
     }
}
```

Then, modify the constructor of the class to have an instance of the value object:

```
... 
...
// THE VALUE OBJECT REFERENCE WITH THE VALUES YOU NEED TO HOLD DURING THE FORM INTERACTION
private CalculatedValues calculatedValues;

WellParameters() {  
    super("Well Parameters", true, true, false, true);
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 385);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    ...//GUI Stuff

    this.add(submitButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // THE VALUE OBJECT REFERENCE...
    calculatedValues = CalculatedValues.makeNew();
}
```

Then, update the reference with the calculation:

```
@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    try {
        if(e.getSource() == measuredDepthT) { 
            //KillWellCalculations.measuredDepth = Integer.parseInt(measuredDepthT.getText());
            // the exceptions thrown can be caught in the catch below and you can display the error message from the value class.
            calculatedValues.setMeasuredDepth(measuredDepthT.getText());

          ...//Others 

            // collect other values as well...

        } else if(e.getSource() == mudInActivePitsT) {
            //KillWellCalculations.mudInActivePits = Double.parseDouble(mudInActivePitsT.getText());
            // do try/catch for the possible runtime exception and display an error message
            calculatedValues.setMudInActivePitsT(mudInActivePitsT.getText());

        }
    } catch (Exception ignore) { 
    }

}
```

The the updates on the final step also using the instance reference:

```
  @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      try {
        if(e.getSource() == submitButton) {
        System.out.println(KillWellCalculations.pumpEfficiency);
        // THE REFERENCES THAT THIS STATIC METHOD USE WERE ALL GARBAGE-COLLECTED AT THE TIME OF THE CALL... IF SHOULD HAVE THE CALCULATED METHODS IN THE VALUE CLASS. SOMETHING LIKE THE FOLLOWING:
        // KillWellCalculations.setPressureBeforeCasingBurstAndFormationFracture(); //Doesn't work
        //KillWellCalculations.setCirculatingPressures();
        //KillWellCalculations.setTriplexPumpCapacity();
        //System.out.println(KillWellCalculations.mudInActivePits);
        //System.out.println(KillWellCalculations.pumpFactor);
        //System.out.println(KillWellCalculations.finalCirculatingPressure);}

        // DO THE FINAL CALCULATION IN A SINGLE METHOD IN THE VALUE OBJECT.
        calculatedValues.doAllCalculations();

        // HERE ARE THE GETTERS FROM THE CALCULATED VALUES OF THE DO ALL CALCULATIONS YOU HAVE TO IMPLEMENT.
        System.out.println(calculatedValues.getMudInActivePits());
        System.out.println(calculatedValues.getPumpFactor());
        System.out.println(calculatedValues.getFinalCirculatingPressure());}

        // CONSIDERING YOU'RE DONE WITH THE VALUES, JUST CLEAR THE INSTANCE VALUES
        // AS THIS REFERENCE IS NOT STATIC AND IT WILL NOT BE GARBAGE-COLLECTED. 
        calculatedValues.clearValues();
    }
    catch(Exception ignore) {}
  }
```

I did some work way back related to GUI... You can see a very similar example at http://code.google.com/p/marcellodesales-cs-research/source/browse/trunk/grad-ste-ufpe-brazil/ptf-add-on-dev/src/br/ufpe/cin/stp/ptfaddon/view/swing/execution/JWizardInternalFrame.java

Good Luck!